# Enable mysqli_stmt::get_result() on hostgator

Tags: php, mysqli

I have got folling error when i had moved my code to server

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

I'm using `Host Gator Shared hosting` and i have updated php version 7.1 as per some online suggestions but no luck.

I know this is solution : **mysqli_stmt :: get_result is Available only with mysqlnd.** but how could i change that from host gator cpanel as there is no such option and also checked `php.ini` had no any clue too.

Comment: Have you turned on the mysqli / mysqlnd extensions in the php.ini?

Comment: I could not find that in php.ini? as i tried find it.